# How can I use a boolean result in place of a logical operator query?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table with entries in the first column and several properties of those entries in other columns. The properties are all calculated via formula except for some that I have manually entered. I am trying to count the number of properties that I have manually entered.

Some Excel functions, such as the `COUNTIF(range, criteria)` function, accept a cell range as one argument and a logical operator query (`=, <>, >, <, >=, <=`) as the other. This works well for static conditions, like comparison against a known value (e.g. `COUNTIF[Table[MyColumn]], <>0`), but I'd like to use the boolean return value of a function in place of the logical operator so I can evaluate every entry on the `[Table[MyColumn]]` range, specifically the (negated) result of `ISFORMULA()`.

Here's some psuedo-code of what I want to do: `COUNTIF([Table[MyColumn]], // check if entry is a formula or manually entered with something like ISFORMULA())`. This would then return a count of all of the manually entered cells in `MyColumn`. All of the cells in `MyColumn` contain numeric values, and I want to count only the ones that weren't generated via formula.

Is it possible to substitute a boolean return value for a query condition like this? If so, is it possible using structured references (`[MyColumn]`) instead of absolute references (`C2:C87`)? Does the operation I am trying to perform require the use of VBA scripts?

Comment: As far as I know, they only work to evaluate with value but not inside: maybe you can use: `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISFORMULA(column))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I can think of. I like the new FILTER() function but you'll need to be on newer version of Excel.

```
=SUM(--ISFORMULA(Table1[MyColumn]))
or
=COUNT(FILTER(Table1[MyColumn],ISFORMULA(Table1[MyColumn])))
```

edit: if you're not an Office 365 (not on latest version of Excel) you might need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter for the first option.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the first is an array formula so "CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER" has to be used when entering.

Comment: @VBasic2008 not true for the current version of Excel, but considering many people aren't on that, I've added a clarification.

Comment: Hours of scouring the internet and not once did FILTER() pop up. Your second method works quite well.